# How to use sidekiq to avoid coupling of two queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Right now I'm using Sidekiq to in parallel calculate two things: `tags` & `categories` of a blog post. This calculation should happen once the post is saved to the database. So I have:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  after_commit :extract_tags_and_categories, if: :saved_change_to_content?

  private

  def extract_tags_and_categories
    TagsExtractorWorker(id)
    CategoriesExtractorWorker(id)
  end
end
```

The problem with that is that I'm using a third party API to help me fetch only the text of the url of a post, and both of them need ithe text of it. So I'm doing:

```
class TagsExtractorWorker < Worker
  def perform(post_id)
    post = Post.find!(post_id)
    text = ThirdPartyAPI.get(post.url)
    # find out the tags here and save it to post.tags
  end
end
```

```
class CategoriesExtractorWorker < Worker
  def perform(post_id)
    post = Post.find!(post_id)
    text = ThirdPartyAPI.get(post.url)
    # find out the categories here and save it to post.categories
  end
end
```

As you can imagine, this API is not free and there is a limit of API calls (I would have to pay for more in order to get be able to call it more times), and right now I'm doing two calls (on both `TagsExtractorWorker` and `CategoriesExtractorWorker`). I would like to be able to call it only once, and use it in both classes. Does sidekiq have something to help me with that?

Also, I can't really use the `Post` class to this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  after_commit :extract_tags_and_categories, if: :saved_change_to_content?

  private

  def extract_tags_and_categories
    text = get_text_somehow()
    TagsExtractorWorker(id, text)
    CategoriesExtractorWorker(id, text)
  end
end
```

Because I'm calling other things (besides these two classes), and I don't want to wait **and** create coupling between things.

My question is: does sidekiq has something to help me with that? Perhaps a middleware that would fetch the text and cache it for other calls.

Comment: Why not just create one worker that does both?

Comment: because that would couple these two things, when they shouldn't be coupled.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cache the HTTP response with your HTTP client, if your third-party API responds with adequate HTTP caching headers.

I don't know of anything in Sidekiq that does that for you. Personally, I've used https://github.com/plataformatec/faraday-http-cache (with a cache store of memcache or redis) for this in the past.

Of course, this will be an option for you only if you can add the caching middleware to your `ThirdPartyAPI` HTTP client.

If that works, then your Sidekiq workers can continue to call through `ThirdPartyAPI` as they are coded to do now without actually hitting your third party (and counting against your quota).